# Package function not evaluating

Tags: evaluation, packages

I have a short package like this:

```
BeginPackage["FunctionAnalysis`",{"Global`"}];
MonoIntervals::usage="returns monotonic intervals of given function";
Begin["`Private`"];
FunctionAnalysis`Private`MonoIntervals[func_[arg_],var_]:={Reduce[D[func[arg],var]>0,var]}
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

I include it, and when I call, for example:

```
MonoIntervals[Sin[x],x]
```

it executes `MonoIntervals`.
The problems occurs when I try to call `MonoIntervals` with functions like:

```
f[x_]:=x^2+2*x-10
MonoIntervals[f[x],x]
```

this results in

```
Out[25]=MonoIntervals[-10 + 2 x + x^2, x]
```

Why doesn't the function execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MonoIntervals[f[x],x]` will evaluate like this:

1. `MonoIntervals[f[x], x]`
2. `MonoIntervals[x^2+2*x-10, x]`

And it stops there because `x^2+2*x-10` doesn't match the pattern `func_[arg_]`.  What precisely are you trying to achieve by using this pattern?

Comment: I am trying to get intervals where given function is positive. What pattern would suit for my case? I thought I have to use `func_[arg_]`, if I replace it with `MonoIntervals[func_,arg_]` and use later in `Reduce[D[func,arg]>0,arg]` it still doesn't evaluate.

Comment: @KristiansKuhta Have you seen [the tutorial on patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html)?  If you are still unsure about why your function behaves the way it does, it's a good idea to stop for a moment and read through it.